# sql same column different condition

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table a containing ax, ay, I have another table b containing ax, and some other things.

I'm trying to select the count of total ax, ax inserted into b, and ax not inserted into b.

I have

```
SELECT
    COUNT(a.ax) AS p,
    COUNT(a.ax) AS q,
FROM 
    a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.ay = b.ay
WHERE b.ay is NULL;
```

This is returning me a table - but both counts are 2. I'm not sure how to separate the conditions while keeping the left join for one of them.

Any advice is appreciated- thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need something like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(r.hnum) AS inserted
FROM 
    h
LEFT JOIN r ON h.hnum = r.hnum;
```

or you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.hnum IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As noninserted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.hnum IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) As inserted
FROM 
    h
LEFT JOIN r ON h.hnum = r.hnum;
```

Here's [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee1a7/1) for conditional aggregation.

To deal with duplicates in `r`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.hnum IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As noninserted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN r.hnum IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) As inserted
FROM 
    h
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT hnum FROM r) r ON h.hnum = r.hnum;
```

Here's [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84b00/2) for conditional aggregation with duplicates.

`JOIN` and `COUNT (DISTINCT)` with calculated field:

```
SELECT result.total As "Total", 
       result.inserted as "Inserted", 
       result.total - result.inserted as "Noninserted"
FROM

( SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT h.hnum) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.hnum) AS inserted
FROM 
    h
LEFT JOIN r ON h.hnum = r.hnum ) result;
```

and the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84b00/3) for this one as well

Comment: Sorry, forgot `,`.  Try now.

Comment: My bad. Forgot about `WHEN`.

Comment: I used `DISTINCT` in sub-query.

Comment: Yes,  you can.  It will take additional sub-query though.

Comment: Posted an "equation"  solution as well.